# Three.js: cause an Object3D to travel parallel to my camera's X axis

Tags: three.js

Say I have a simple triangle as the only element/child in an `Object3D` class.  I have a `PerspectiveCamera` looking at it, and I would like to have the `Object3D` travel down the camera's positive X axis, say, when I press a key.

How can I manipulate things so that the `Object3D` travels parallel along the camera's X axis?  In looking at the inner workings of the `PerspectiveCamera`, I see members for things like `matrixWorld` and `matrixWorldInverse` but am not sure what they represent or how best to use them here.

Can I use the camera's `matrixWorldInverse` matrix to get the Object3D into camera coordinates, then move the object along the camera's x-axis (which I'm not sure how to find, as I don't see an entry for it in `PerspectiveCamera`, though I may not be seeing it) then multiply the Object3D by the 'matrixWorld' matrix again to move it back to world coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making your object a child of your camera? Then any movement of the camera would affect your object. And if you place the camera lets say on the y-z plane of your object, then any movement of the object on its x-axis will also appear to be on the x-axis of the camera.

Comment: That's a good idea, unfortunately I'd only want the object to move parallel to my camera's x axis at certain times-- it wouldn't be a 'child' of the camera most of the time.

Comment: OK but still if you place the camera on the y-z plane and have it lookat somewhere on the y-z plane (ie x=0) then any motion of your object on its x-axis would appear to also be as movement on the x-axis of the camera.